# Confusion regarding laziness

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I have a function

```
myLength = foldl (\ x _ -> x + 1) 0
```

which fails with stack overflow with input around 10^6 elements (myLength [1..1000000] fails). I believe that is due to the thunk build up since when I replace foldl with foldl', it works. 
So far so good.

But now I have another function to reverse a list :

```
myReverse = foldl (\ acc x -> x : acc) []
```

which uses the lazy version foldl (*instead* of foldl')

When I do 
`myLength . myReverse $ [1..1000000]`. 
This time it works fine. I fail to understand why foldl works for the later case and not for former?

To clarify here myLength uses foldl' while myReverse uses foldl

Comment: I get a stack overflow exception for both cases.

Comment: No, that's just the logo at the top of the website you're looking at ;) (I don't get an exception for myReverse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my best guess, though I'm no expert on Haskell internals (yet).

While building the thunk, Haskell allocates all the intermediate accumulator variables on the *heap*.

When performing the addition as in `myLength`, it needs to use the stack for intermediate variables. See [this page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27). Excerpt:

> The problem starts when we finally evaluate z1000000:
>
> Note that z1000000 = z999999 +
>   1000000. So 1000000 is pushed on the stack. Then z999999 is evaluated.
>
> Note that z999999 = z999998 + 999999.
>   So 999999 is pushed on the stack. Then
>   z999998 is evaluated:
>
> Note that z999998 = z999997 + 999998.
>   So 999998 is pushed on the stack. Then
>   z999997 is evaluated:

However, when performing list construction, here's what I think happens (this is where the guesswork begins):

> When evaluating z1000000:
>
> Note that z1000000 = 1000000 :
>   z999999. So 1000000 is stored inside
>   z1000000, along with a link (pointer)
>   to z999999. Then z999999 is evaluated.
>
> Note that z999999 = 999999 : z999998.
>   So 999999 is stored inside z999999,
>   along with a link to z999998. Then
>   z999998 is evaluated.
>
> etc.

Note that z999999, z999998 etc. changing from a not-yet-evaluated expression into a single list item is an everyday Haskell thing :)

Since z1000000, z999999, z999998, etc. are all on the heap, these operations don't use any stack space. QED.

Comment: Actually, both arguments to `(:)` are stored as pointers, not just the tail. In other words `(+)` is strict in both it arguments (they need to be fully evaluated), but `(:)` is lazy in its arguments (they can be thunks).